# Address validation during user sign up using geocoder in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am trying to include address validation during user sign up in ruby on rails. The user has to input their address in the form of street address, city, and zipcode. I implemented some address validation in the user controller using this:

```
    after_validation :geocode
    has_secure_password

    
    validates :address, presence: true
    validate :found_address_presence

    def found_address_presence
        if latitude.blank? || longitude.blank?
            errors.add(:address, " wasn't found.")
        end
    end

    def full_address
        [address, city, state, zip_code, 'USA'].compact.join(', ')
    end
```

However, this always returns the error that the address was not found, even when the address is valid. I have confirmed that the addresses I inputted are real and work when the validation is removed. Why is this not working? It seems like the latitudes and longitudes are always blank, but they seem to be added appropriately when the address validation is removed.

Comment: Can you add the logs from the error, and maybe the code that you are using to test the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that the first line `after_validation :geocode` is not filling in the longitudes and latitudes until after validation. So `validate :found_address_presence` will always have blank latitudes and longitudes. If you change this first line to `before_validation :geocode`, then I think it should work.